# Is there a way to access the namespace of a Python function defined with a decorator?

Tags: python, namespaces, python-decorators

Let's say I use a caching decorator to define a new function, like this:

```
def cached(funcy):
    cache = dict()
    def cache_funcy(x):
        if x in cache:
            return cache[x]
        else:
            print cache
            result = funcy(x)
            cache[x] = result
            return result
    return cache_funcy

@cached
def triple(x):
    return 3*x
```

Calling the function `triple` four times produces the following output:

```
>>> triple(1)
{}
3
>>> triple(2)
{1: 3}
6
>>> triple(2)
6
>>> triple(4)
{1: 3, 2: 6}
12
```

My understanding is that the function `triple` has access to a dictionary that is locally called `cache` because this dictionary existed in the namespace in which `triple` was defined. This dictionary is not directly accessible in the outer global scope.

Is it possible to access this `cache` dictionary through some kind of attribute of the function `triple`?

Note: I want to know if it's possible to do this without explicitly making `cache` an attribute of `triple` via something like `cache_funcy.cache = cache` in the definition of `cached`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, this dict is *not* stored in the local-namespace of the function, it is a free variable, so it is stored in the function closure. **In Python 2**, consider:

```
In [1]: def cached(funcy):
   ...:     cache = dict()
   ...:     def cache_funcy(x):
   ...:         if x in cache:
   ...:             return cache[x]
   ...:         else:
   ...:             print cache
   ...:             result = funcy(x)
   ...:             cache[x] = result
   ...:             return result
   ...:     return cache_funcy
   ...:
   ...: @cached
   ...: def triple(x):
   ...:     return 3*x
   ...:

In [2]: triple(1)
{}
Out[2]: 3

In [3]: triple(2)
{1: 3}
Out[3]: 6
```

And now:

```
In [5]: triple.func_closure
Out[5]:
(<cell at 0x10e4e7be8: dict object at 0x10e7ec910>,
 <cell at 0x10e7b2590: function object at 0x10e81ede8>)
```

The first cell contains the `dict`, the second cell contains the function that is being decorated (which is also a free variable). So, you can use:

```
In [6]: triple.func_closure[0].cell_contents
Out[6]: {1: 3, 2: 6}

In [7]: triple.func_closure[0].cell_contents[2] = 'foo'

In [8]: triple(2)
Out[8]: 'foo'
```

Note, the attributes of functions in **Python 3** are a little different, here, there is a direct attribute `__closure__`, so:

```
In [4]: triple.__closure__
Out[4]:
(<cell at 0x1026dbc78: dict object at 0x1028d1bd0>,
 <cell at 0x1026dbf48: function object at 0x1028e59d8>)
```

*And actually, in Python 2, since Python 2.6, these underscore attributes were added for forward compatibility, so this attribute exists as well unless you are on a version below Python 2.6.*

So for compatibility reasons, you should probably use `__closure__`